# window width changes when inspector open

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, width

In Chrome (on windows) and IE9 when I have the inspector open the width being returned by `$(window).width()` varies.

The width it returns when the inspector is closed is incorrect and causes my divs to shift down as there is not enough room on the page to fit them.

This does not seem to be a problem on my mac though where the browser width stays constant.

This is not an issue regarding scroll bars as the scroll bar is always present due to a lot of content.

Interestingly if I drag the inspector down so it reveals more of the page and less of the inspector it causes the same problem on page refresh.

Any ideas what could be causing the problem?

Comment: Just undock your inspector so it's a second window... Unless you still experience the same problem, which would be extremely weird?

Comment: I could see it affecting the height, I'm not sure why it would affect the width.

Comment: @meagar you misunderstand my problem.  The inspector being open is what makes the width return the correct value.  With it closed it returns the incorrect value (same with it undocked).  Physically the width does not change on screen with or without the inspector open, however the width returned by jquery does.

Comment: Ah yes, I did misunderstand then. I thought you were seeing the correct value when the inspector was closed, and an incorrect value when shown.